# Ruby on Rails - can't render a variable in a function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I have some HAML code like this:

```
.clearfix
  =f.label t("labels.shortened_urls.fqdn_url")
  =f.url_field :fqdn_url, {:readonly => true}
.span1
  =link_to((t "links.shortened_urls.view"), f.object.fqdn_url(true), :target => :_blank)
  .clippy-container=clippy(fqdn_url,"#ffffff")
```

it does nto render because of the last line. If I change the last line to a simple string like this, it will work:

```
.clippy-container=clippy("test","#ffffff")
```

but I am not certain of the variables syntax that I need to use and I tried this:

```
.clippy-container=clippy(fqdn_url,"#ffffff")
```

or this:

```
.clippy-container=clippy(:fqdn_url,"#ffffff")
```

but none of them work.  Any idea how to make it work with that fqdn_url variable?

Thanks!

Comment: Define "doesn't work". What happens instead of what you expect? I ask because `clippy(fqdn_url,"#ffffff")` should be correct, so long as `fqdn_url` actually returns what you expect it to.

Comment: @AlexWayne the clippy little widget just doesn't get displayed when I try to use variations of my attempts.  But it displays and works if I use the "test" string

Comment: Could you copy and paste the source code of your page (the part with the <object> only though)?

Comment: No idea what a "clippy widget" is, but look at the generated html on the rendered page.  What's in the spot wher ethe text should be be, instead of that text?

Comment: I got it to render like this: .clippy-container=clippy(:fqdn_url.to_s,"#ffffff") but when I press copy, it takes the fqdn_url.to_s as a literal string instead of copying displaying the contents of that variable.

Comment: Where do you *set* the variable? If it's part of the form object shouldn't you reference the object as well as the accessor? In the `url_field` the helper grabs the value from the object.

Comment: First lesson about rails: It's just ruby.  `clippy(:fqdn_url.to_s,"#ffffff")` there fore is the same as `clippy('fqdn_url',"#ffffff")` which of course isn't what you want. If you don't know the difference between strings, symbols and method calls, I'd recommend taking a step back and brushing on ruby before going much farther into rails.

Comment: Right, I don't want the string literal. I want the value in that string. That value is displayed elsewhere so I know there is a value.

Comment: @Genadinik But so far everywhere you display it, AFAIC, you're using a helper, or by using the form object. Why aren't you in the place where it doesn't work? Is it a route? Is it a model property? What is it?

Comment: its a variable that is generated on the fly

Comment: @Genadinik Where? Also, please use the `@` convention if you're replying to a specific person, otherwise they won't know you've replied unless they explicitly check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `fqdn_url.to_s`?

Comment: `fqdn_url` looks like a rails route helper, which should always return a string.  This shouldn't really really affect anything at all.

Comment: Right. I suspect the code is rightly generated, there must be a problem with the swf not found.